# BitDefender blocking Sec.Se

Tags: support, status-norepro

Heads up.

BitDefender on Mac is preventing people from accessing this site. People get this warning: 
[image]

Comment: any other stackexchange site with a SE domain? like  https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @schroeder nope, that is fine.

Comment: @schroeder it's only the home page, direct links to questions are fine.

Comment: Might it be because some quesitons contain code from malware? A dumb scanner could interpret that as the site being infected by it...

Comment: FYI - no longer an issue. Just tested

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it seems to have been a one-off non-reproducible issue.